# I can't deploy large contracts with Optimizer enabled

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy

I'm aware since Spurious Dragon there's a size limit for the contracts, I cloned this [repository](http://github.com/atlantis-loans/atlantis-protocol-bsc) to test it locally and learn about how everything works, but I can't deploy some contracts due to the size being larger than the limit.

I'm using hardhat and my deploy script looks something like this:

```
async function main() {       
const Comptroller = await ethers.getContractFactory('Comptroller');
        const comptroller = await Comptroller.deploy();
        console.log("comptroller deployed to:", comptroller.address);
 
}
main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

This is on my hardhat.config:

```
    module.exports = {
      solidity: "0.5.16",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 20
        }
      },
  networks: {
    testnet: {
      url: secret.url,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
      accounts: [secret.key]
    }
```

This is what I'm using to deploy:

```
npx hardhat --network testnet run scripts/deploy1.js
```

I'm getting the error from the deployment that the size of the contracts is too large, so how can they have deployed the same code that is exceeding the size and I'm not able to deploy it?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: `ProviderError: max code size exceeded
    at HttpProvider.request 
 at LocalAccountsProvider.request
at processTicksAndRejections
at EthersProviderWrapper.send`

Comment: Have you tried after change the solidity version?

Comment: I tried and got some deployed but others still didn't deploy. I'm curious why would a solidity change affect this?

Comment: @SamuelVillegas The repo uses eth-saddle to manage compilation and deployment. If I'm reading the config file correctly they enable in ganache `allowUnlimitedContractSize` to support arbitrary large contracts.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your help! I've tried adding the allowUnlimitedContractSize configuration to my hardhat deploy script but still can't deploy to the BSC Testnet, wondering if eth-saddle is allowing large contracts to be deployed even in mainnets and hardhat is not. Going to explore eth-saddle now.

Comment: You can take a look at the configuration file, https://github.com/atlantis-loans/atlantis-protocol-bsc/blob/main/saddle.config.js. It doesn't include BSC but it has other networks like rinkeby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optimizer is supposed to help your large code achieve maximum efficiency so it runs and can be deployed. Increasing the runs value from 20 to 500 may work.

Comment: By increasing `runs`, you are telling the optimizer that the functions on the contract are going to be called very often, so the optimizer will try and make functions cheaper to call, even if this means it has to inline/repeat some code… resulting in a larger contract with higher one-time initial deployment gas cost. So what the OP wants to be doing here is the _opposite_, to _lower_ `runs`, to encourage the optimizer to save on initial deployment gas — in order to lower this cost, the optimizer will try and make the contract bytecode smaller, which might bring it back below the limit.

Comment: Thank you for this, I finally understand what the optimizer really does and how it does it. This would've probably taken me a longer time to figure out

Answer (score 3):

I came across same problem once, this setting below worked for me

```
settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
        details: { yul: false },
      },
    },
```

Comment: This was perfect for me! Can you point me towards some documentation for the `details`? It's difficult to find advanced optimizer settings for this.